# Problem with removing category from WordPress post

Tags: wordpress

For some reason I seem to be unable to remove the category "Uncategorized" from posts on my WordPress page http://www.karlshamnsaikido.se/. Since it's in Swedish it says "OKATEGORISERADE" instead of "Uncategorized" though. Whenever I edit a post and uncheck the box for "Uncategorized" and press update it just get checked again when the page reloads.

I have tried to do this logged in as administrator as well but it doesn't help. 
I have also tried removing the category from the category administration page and receive no error message when I do, but it just comes back.

Has anyone come across this problem and know how to correct it?

Comment: Is this self-hosted or from WordPress.com?

Comment: It is self-hosted running version 3.4

Comment: Questions about self hosted blogs are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

The category "Uncategorized" is a default category.

You have to have a default category (which means at least one) in Wordpress.

However, you could change the "Uncategorized" category to a more imposing one as such "Blog", "Stories", etc, which would make the default (say for example, blog) category "Blog" and list all uncategorized posts as under "Blog".

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem was twofold. I'm not even able to remove the category from a single post.

Comment: It needs a category by default. Tags are optional, though.

Comment: Since you're hosting it, you could try to remove part of the code where it shows the Category or something, so it won't display below a post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the wordpress user did not have the correct permissions to perform updates in the database.